# Телеграм бот. Прикрепленная ссылка

Tags: python, link, telegram-bot

Делаю с помощью Python и telebot бота для телеграма.

Возник вопрос: отправляю пользователю ссылки, а первая прикрепляется. Как отменить прикрепление?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо при отправке сообщения пользователю использовать опциональный параметр `disable_web_page_preview` метода [sendMessage](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#sendmessage).

> `disable_web_page_preview` - Disables link previews for links in this message

Передавайте `true` для того, чтобы отменить предпросмотр вебстраницы. По умолчанию `disable_web_page_preview` установлен в `false`.

Comment: Простите, что так долго принимал ответ. Спасибо!